# IntelliJでionicしたい

Tags: android-studio, cordova, intellij-idea

IntelliJにて作成した既存のcordova/phonegapプロジェクトへionicを追加（？）するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？
プラグインにてサポートされていると書いていますが使用方法がわかりません。

また、新規プロジェクト作成時に設定する方法もあれは教えていただけると嬉しいです。

ちなみに使用中のバージョンは

IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate

です。

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1):

他サイトで解決できました！
回答を記載しておきます。

「ionic start」にて作成したプロジェクトをIntelliJで開くことができました！

「Import Project」ではなく「Open」から作成したAppのフォルダを選択することでできました。
あとは、設定からexecutableへ「/usr/local/bin/ionic」を選択すれば実行できました！
詳しくは「https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-phonegap-cordova.html」を参照ください。

既存プロジェクトへは試していませんが、同様の操作でいける気がします。

また、「Import Project」でもできるのかもしれませんが私のやり方が悪いのか「www」フォルダなどが含まれませんでした。